# How to get the reason of why a server certificate is invalid with .NET HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, https

```
Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

So there are lots of answers out there regarding this exception, but most of them seem to be solved by saying "just don't use an invalid certificate".

Fair enough, but I know there can be a multitude of reasons of why a certificate is considered invalid (see: https://badssl.com/), but the exception mentioned just tells us "it's invalid" and I didn't find any properties on that exception with more details.

So the code could look something like this. How do I figure out why the certificate is considered invalid? Is it even possible using HttpClient or do I have to examine the certificate another way?

```
var client = new HttpClient();
try
{
    using (var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://expired.badssl.com/"))
    {
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(msg))
        {
            // do stuff with the response
        }
    }
}
catch (AuthenticationException ex)
{
    // why is the certificate invalid?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is well written here:
https://ardalis.com/automatically-detect-expiring-https-ssl-certificates/

Basically you issue a web request and handle server certificate validation callback where you are able to find out reason for SSL error